# Default node_modules in react native

Tags: react-native, node-modules

I want to configure the default node_modules when I use:

```
react-native init NAME
```

Every time I use init command, I see a `eslint-plugin-react-native` package is installed by default!

I tried to uninstall it globally but no difference!

```
npm uninstall -g eslint-plugin-react-native
```

How I can remove a package from default packages?

Comment: @grizzthedj any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tom Hastjarjanto](https://github.com/Intellicode) (Owner of `eslint-plugin-react-native`) said:

> it is a dependency of react-native itself so thats why its installed by default.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native/issues/194)